# Can I modify a whole bunch of webpages on CQ using a single JSON object?

Tags: json, curl, aem, jcr

I used curl to get the JSON for a bunch of hierarchically occurring webpages, and modified every occurrence of a particular property. My JSON object is intact and I would like to know whether it is possible to write back the entire JSON as-is to recreate the webpages. I am unable to think of any method to update each occurrence of the property, meaning, how would I find the location of the property each time and update it's contents?

Comment: If your JSON has a path to each page node that needs to be updated, you could write a servlet and pass the json into it, parse through it, and update each node.

Comment: Thanks @Woodifer. I figured I cannot do it the easy way. Also, I do not have the path to each node. However, I can reconstruct the path since I have a simple website structure. I'm parsing the JSON and updating each node back to the JCR.